# deinterlace on the fly with an external recorder

Tags: digital-recording

Is anyone aware of an external recorder that can deinterlace on the fly? I know that the Shogun can downconvert 4k to 1080p so that you retain more sharpness, and the Pix devices can also do similar things as well as changing framerates and removing pulldowns.

Answer (score 1):

The Blackmagic Design Tenarex 2D will convert a signal from interlaced to progressive on the fly: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/teranex/processing

It doesn't record, but there are very inexpensive recording devices that will take a progressive signal and give you a digital asset from that (such as the HyperDeck Shuttle: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/hyperdeckshuttle)

Comment: know of anything smaller? im thinking of an on camera solution; sorry should have mentioned that in my post